# Django social authentication with registration extra fields

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I want to do a social authentication with Google and Facebook. For that I have use social-auth-app-django. When I login with using Google it will directly create an account in django user model and redirect to my URL. But I want to fill extra required details of user, after entering detail create user after user's confirmation and don't want to directly login new user and redirect to my authenticated page.
Any suggestion is always appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's basically the purpose of the `partial pipelines` feature on `python-social-auth` ([docs](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#partial-pipeline)). The idea is to pause the authentication flow at any time and resume it later, it's commonly used to ask for more details to the user, or to just send a validation email.

Check the example application [here](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-examples/blob/master/example-django/), in the [settings](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-examples/blob/master/example-django/example/settings.py#L211-L225) it overrides the default pipeline with one that will ask the user for their email address.